# Is it possible to create index with specified value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique

I would like to store jobs in a collection with these attributes: state & hash_value.
When the job is first created, state will be pending. I want to allow for 1 job with state pending and unique hash_value at a time.
Lets say there’s hash_value 123 and state pending, if I create a job with hash_value 123 and state pending I want the index error to be triggered.
But if there is only a job with hash_value 123 and state failed in the collection, I want to allow job creation as there is no hash_value 123 and state pending.
I guess I can query the collection first before creation, but I just want to know if this is achievable through unique index. Thanks

```
_id: 1,
state: 'pending',
hash_value: 'd1061af8b1a46bdc74329a16b05f1408f0368925'

_id: 2,
state: 'failed',
hash_value: 'd1061af8b1a46bdc74329a16b05f1408f0368925'

_id: 3,
state: 'pending',
hash_value: '405e619470ae575e83f62625d0bb3cc779bea2d5'
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample JSON data?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ok I've added it

Comment: This seems like you are asking how to create a unique, partial, compound index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Joe said, what I needed is partial filter expression to make sure that the index is applied only on jobs with state pending

```
await db.collection('job').createIndex(
  { state: 1, hash_value: 1 },
  {
    partialFilterExpression: { state: { $eq: "pending" } },
    name: "pending_token_idx",
    unique: true,
  },
 )
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.